# Upload Image MVC always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, httppostedfilebase

Hi everyone i am trying to upload a simple image but the HttpPostedFileBase is always remaining null. This is my code i dont know what i am doing wrong.

This is my code in the design view:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>PictureModel</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.PrivacyTypeID) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.DropDownList("PrivacyTypeID", null, new { name = "PrivacyTypeID", title = "Please select privacy type.", id = "PrivacyTypeID" }) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PrivacyTypeID) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.File1) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        **<input type="file" name="File1" />**
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.File1) %>
    </div>        
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description) %>
    </div>
```

And here is the code in my controller:

public ActionResult AddPicture(Guid id, PictureModel model, HttpPostedFileBase File1)
        {
            try
            {

```
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    Guid albumid = id;

                    if (File1 != null)
                    {
                        var physicalPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Gallery"), System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File1.FileName));
                        File1.SaveAs(physicalPath);
                        PicturesBL pictures = new PicturesBL();
```

Can anyone please tell me what is the problem??

Comment: Forgot to show you the initial begin form tag<% using (Html.BeginForm("AddPicture", "Album", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
   { %>

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41347644/asp-net-mvc-upload-photo-httppostedfilebase-is-null Here is my problem, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone please tell me what is the problem??

There's nothing wrong with the code you have shown. I suspect that the problem comes from the fact that you are submitting this form using an AJAX call and not a normal submit. But as you know you cannot upload files using AJAX. That's why your code is not working. If you want to upload files using AJAX you could use some client side plugin such as [`Uploadify`](http://www.uploadify.com/) or [`Fine uploader`](http://fineuploader.com/). This can also be done natively in HTML5 using the new [`File API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications). Of course this will only work in modern browsers that support it. If you need to support legacy browsers some of the available client side upload plugins might help you.

Comment: im using a normal submit :

Comment: Then this should work. You may take a look at the [`following post`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc-3-0/5193851#5193851) for a complete working example. Phil Haack also blogged about file uploads in ASP.NET MVC here: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This was driving me crazy too. After hours I realized, that

```
@Scripts.Render( "~/bundles/jquerymobile")
```

in _Layout.cshtml was causing the problem. When commented out, the upload worked.

See http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-seems-to-clobber-ability-to-upload-files-via-forms for details.

Adding

```
data_ajax="false"
```

attribute to my form solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure model.File1 type is `HttpPostedFileBase`  not `HttpPostedFile` 
and form contains `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` attribute.