# HttpPostedFileBase always remaining null mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, httppostedfilebase

i know that there is a lot of questions like this, but i read them all and null of them solved my problem. Here below im going to show the code that i have in my view and my controller so that you can have an idea of my code.

```
View :
<td><% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"})) { %>
<%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
                <div id="section1"> 
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name) %>
    </div>
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
        <input type="file" name="myfile" id="File5" value="Choose File Banner1" />
     <p>&nbsp;</p>

And here is my controller:
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index(HomeModel model, string submitButton, HttpPostedFileBase myfile)
    {
```

I cant figure out what mite be the problem.. can someone help me please

Comment: everything looks fine to me.. just to make sure, you don't have anyother field in the name `myfile` other than the file control right ?

Comment: no it is the only name :/

Comment: could it be there is something wrong somewhere else that is inflicting in some way ??

Comment: not sure, try the same from beginning, or do some sample application with the upload alone, make sure it works before proceeding.

Comment: i have another application with the same code above and works good.. thats why i thinks the problem is coming from somewhere else ..

Comment: check my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102235/upload-image-mvc-always-null.
Maybe this helps

Answer (score 11):

I also had the same problem and I ended up here while looking for an answer. I had forgotten the enctype parameter in the form definition

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
// form
}
```

Comment: This helped me out. Thanks a lot my friend!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before,
I had to remove the value from the file input to make it work :

```
<input type="file" name="myfile" id="File5" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of causes for this issue:

- You didn't specify the `enctype` attribute on the `<form>` tag
- You didn't give a `name` attribute to your `<input type="file">` tag
- You nested a `<form>` tag in another `<form>`

If none of these are your issue, this is what worked for me: add an HttpPostedFileBase property to your view model (or create a view model with that property).

**View Model**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase MyFile { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new MyViewModel());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase file = viewModel.MyFile;

    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using html attribute "@data_ajax = "false" " in the view, near the enctype

```
(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data", @data_ajax = "false" }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you have a `value=""` set in the input element?

Answer (score 0):

I copied a UI into my working MVC3 application and found upload part starts giving same error. I found out there was an extra form (making it a nested form) in Page Layout. I removed it and everything worked fine for me.